# Import Processing in Eclipse (Android Project)

Tags: android, eclipse, import, processing

I heard about Processing.org, a library in android. All I want is to import this library in Eclipse 2014 (64Bit) to start my mini android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: Download Processing's Android mode.

**Step 2**: Inside that Android mode directory, find an **android-core.zip** file.

**Step 3**: Rename that to **android-core.jar**.

**Step 4**: Add that file to your eclipse classpath.

That's all you need to import the library into eclipse. From there, continue following [this guide](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/wiki/Using-Eclipse-or-Android-Studio-for-Development) (note that this is a different link than the other answer) for project setup and creating an app.